# Elif statement not working as expected while scraping website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been working on my code to retrieve all statements of inmates on death row. This is what I have so far

```
import sqlite3
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import urllib
import urllib3
import ssl
from datetime import datetime

ExecutionID= None
linkLS = None
conn = sqlite3.connect('Deathrow.sqlite')
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Inmates")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Inmates (id integer primary key, Execution text, Lastname text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, Date text, Race text, County text, Laststatement text, LastStatementURL text, InmateInformation, text)")
conn.commit()
url='https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html'
data = requests.get(url,verify = False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "tdcj_table indent"})
headers = table.find_all("th")
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in table.find_all("tr") [1:]:
        
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        ExecutionID= str(cells[0].get_text())
        InmateInformation = 'https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/' + cells[1].a['href']
        linkLS = 'https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/' + cells[2].a['href']
        Lastname = str(cells[3].get_text())
        Firstname = str(cells[4].get_text())
        TDJC = str(cells[5].get_text())
        Age = int(cells[6].get_text())
        Date = (cells[7].get_text())
        Date = datetime.strptime(Date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        Race = str(cells[8].get_text())
        County = str(cells[9].get_text())
        print ("--- retrieving execution data for execution ID",ExecutionID,Lastname,",",Firstname," ---")
        if ExecutionID == "545":
            linkLS == "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html"
        elif ExecutionID == "544":
            linkLS == "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/pruettrobertlast.html"
        elif ExecutionID == "552":
            linkLS =="https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/no_last_statement.html"
        else:
            r = requests.get(linkLS,verify = False)
            print ("--- retrieving statement", ExecutionID," ---")
            print (linkLS)
            document = urllib.request.urlopen(linkLS)
            html = document.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
            pattern = re.compile("Last Statement:")
            try:
                statement = soup.find(string=pattern).findNext('p').contents[0]
                statement = str(statement)
                statement = statement.lstrip(' ')
                statement = statement.rstrip(' ')
                statement = statement.replace("<span class=", "")
                statement = statement.replace("</span>", "")
                statement = statement.replace('"', "")
                statement = statement.replace("text_italic>", "")
            except Exception:
                    print("An error has occured while retrieving the statement. Proceeding...")
                    statement = ""
                    continue

        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Inmates (Execution, Lastname, Firstname, TDCJNumber, Age, Date, Race, County, Laststatement, LastStatementURL, InmateInformation) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", (str(ExecutionID), str(Firstname), str(Lastname), str(TDJC), int(Age), str(Date), str(Race), str(County), str(statement), str(linkLS), str(InmateInformation)))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print ("Retrieval complete. Open deathrow.sqlite to see the data. Execute gword.py to create the wordcloud.")
```

What the program does is:
retrieve the information of the inmate
retrieve the link to the last statement of the inmate and show the link in the output
extract the last statement of the inmate
This information is being put in a sqlite database.

So normal output is:

```
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 581 Balentine , John  ---
--- retrieving statement 581  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/balentinejohnlast.html
```

Now I've been running in just one more issue: The links to the statements of 3 inmates are wrong. I know this because I checked the page source of [death row inmates](https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html). Let's take inmate 545 for example: For inmate 545 the link is "/death_row/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html" when it should be "/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html". This causes my program not to retrieve the last statement of this inmate.

I tried to tackle this issue with "if" and "elif" statements to deal with these issues. My code is not working as expected however. In output I get:

```
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/shoreanthonylast.html
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 545 Cardenas , Ruben  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 544 Pruett , Robert  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 543 Preyor , Taichin  ---
--- retrieving statement 543  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/preyortaichinlast.html
```

As you can see it does not retrieve the last statement of inmate 545 and immediately jumps to inmate 544 and 543.
I'm having a hard time to understand why this goes wrong. I'm assigning linkLS to the correct links, depending on the execution number. But something seems to go haywire in my code. I thought the program would exit the elif statements once the execution number is found, but that does not seem to happen. am I on the right track here?

Comment: You haven't said what the exact problem is.  In that sample output, the third ExecutionID is "543", which does not match any of the `if` conditions, so the code goes into the `else` condition.  What is the **actual problem** with this output?

Comment: I have clarified my issue by adding more details!

Comment: Underneath `if ExecutionID == "545":`, you have this `linkLS == "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html"`.  But that is wrong because you are using `==` which is a **comparison**, not an **assignment**.  I think you meant `linkLS =`, not `linkLS ==`.

Answer (score 1):

The high level synopsis is that you're authoring some code
which is not well-structured, and testing hasn't gone smoothly yet.

You would benefit from extracting some helper functions,
so instead of a giant `for` loop you have a small
loop body that makes a couple of calls to helpers.
That lets you debug smaller chunks of code,
where there's less happening and there's less room
for bugs to hide.
Plus it would let you exercise each helper from a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase),
without needing to re-run the whole program
and wait on web GETs.

Ok, on to the nitty gritty.
You wrote:

```
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    ...
    linkLS = some_base_url + cells[2].a["href"]
    ...
    if ExecutionID == "545":
        linkLS == alternate_url_545
    elif ExecutionID == "544":
        linkLS == alternate_url_544
    elif ExecutionID == "552":
        linkLS == alternate_url_552
    else:
        r = requests.get(linkLS, verify=False)
        print("--- retrieving statement", ExecutionID, " ---")
        ....
```

That's not what you want.

Author's Intent was to parse out some fields, including an url,
fixup the url in a handful of problematic special cases,
and then fetch the url contents to go on and do stuff with it.

What you wrote executes one of two things in the middle. It either

1. chooses an alternate url in a handful of special cases, or it
2. fetches the standard url if we're not in a special case.

Additionally, evaluating `x == y` and (silently) discarding the `bool`
comparison result is very different from assigning `x = y`.
Be careful when assigning to `linkLS`.

Repairing the code is pretty simple, we just un-indent the body:

```
    if ExecutionID == "545":
        linkLS = alternate_url_545
    elif ExecutionID == "544":
        linkLS = alternate_url_544
    elif ExecutionID == "552":
        linkLS = alternate_url_552

    r = requests.get(linkLS, verify = False)
    print("--- retrieving ...
```

But a better approach would be to bury the special casing
in a helper function.

```
def adjust_url(linkLS, ExecutionID):
    if ExecutionID == "545":
        linkLS = alternate_url_545
    elif ExecutionID == "544":
        linkLS = alternate_url_544
    elif ExecutionID == "552":
        linkLS = alternate_url_552

    return linkLS

...
for ...
    r = requests.get(adjust_url(linkLS, ExecutionID), verify = False)
    print("--- retrieving ...
```

And rather than a bunch of `if` statements, consider using a
[dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)
which stores the special cases:

```
def adjust_url(linkLS, ExecutionID):
    return special_case_url.get(ExecutionID, linkLS)
```

Comment: `linkLS == alternate_url_545` You made the same mistake OP did.  This is a **comparison**, not an **assignment**, because of the double equal sign.

Comment: Stupid I didn't notice that. It is indeed a comparison while I had to assign the correct link to linkLS...  I got it working now,Thanks!